# How do I list all the ACLs of a directory tree?

Tags: bash, debian, acl

I have a Debian Fileserver with ACLs. 
With getfacl -R I get all the files, but I only need the directories.

I tried to only list the directories and then input that to getfacl:

```
ls -R | grep ":$" | cut -d: -f 1 > file.txt
```

and then getfacl `cat file.txt`. But a lot of directories have spaces, and we can't change them.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not really hard, is it, but only painful.  Sorry about that.  For reliable performance, you may have to write and compile your own command-line tool using the library interface summarized by `man 5 acl`.

If you happen to use Python (I don't use it myself, being of the Perl habit, rather), then there appears to exist the Debian package *python-pylibacl,* which looks as though it might do what you want.

Good luck.